# Color individual bar in google bar chart

Tags: javascript, php, json, google-api, bar-chart

I have a google bar chart which gets data from json. It is monthly customer flow chart and it displays all the days of month and respective customer flow. Now i want the bar which shows max customer flow out of all to be colored in blue and rest would be grey.
Eg:

```
^
|      ...
|-----Grey--------
|-----Blue------------
|-----Grey----------
|-----Grey--------
|-----Grey----------
|      ...
|__________________________________>
```

This is part of json:

```
$table = array();
$table['cols'] = array(
    /* define your DataTable columns here
     * each column gets its own array
     * syntax of the arrays is:
     * label => column label
     * type => data type of column (string, number, date, datetime, boolean)
     */
    // I assumed your first column is a "string" type
    // and your second column is a "number" type
    // but you can change them if they are not
    array('label' => 'Dates as in '.$mon, 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'Revenue', 'type' => 'number')
);

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $temp = array();
    // each column needs to have data inserted via the $temp array
    $temp[] = array('v' => $r['date']);
    $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['amount']); // typecast all numbers to the appropriate type (int or float) as needed - otherwise they are input as strings

    // insert the temp array into $rows
    $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
}

// populate the table with rows of data
$table['rows'] = $rows;

// encode the table as JSON
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) one way of doing this.

```
 var options  = {
    legend: { position: 'bottom', maxLines: 3 },
    bar: { groupWidth: '50%' },
    colors:[{color:'#FF9900', darker:'#FF9900'},{color:'#3366CC', darker:'#3366CC'},{color:'#DC3912', darker:'#DC3912'}]
  };
```

Google api allows to customize the bar graph colors while writing the script to enable and draw the charts.options have different attributes to customize. The above code needs to be added in script block of the code while drawing the chart. I would recommend to go through the following link.

2) the other and recommended by google.

There are three different ways to choose the colors, and data table showcases them all: RGB values, English color names, and a CSS-like declaration:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }],
        ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333'],            // RGB value
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver'],            // English color name
    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2' ], // CSS-style declaration
      ]);
```

for further more styling

```
  function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Visitations', { role: 'style' } ],
    ['2010', 10, 'color: gray'],
    ['2010', 14, 'color: #76A7FA'],
    ['2020', 16, 'opacity: 0.2'],
    ['2040', 22, 'stroke-color: #703593; stroke-width: 4; fill-color: #C5A5CF'],
    ['2040', 28, 'stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 8; fill-color: #BC5679; fill-opacity: 0.2'],
  ]);
```

[Please refer here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#Colors) for the documentation with some excellent examples.